# Binary file is not creating, no errors given C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a function reading hex string from the resource:

```
std::string hex_string;
HRSRC h = FindResource(GMS(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(DEMO_TEXT), MAKEINTRESOURCE(TEXTFILE));
HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(GMS(), h);
DWORD hSize = SizeofResource(GMS(), h);
char* hFinal = (char*)LockResource(hData);
hex_string.assign(hFinal, hSize);
```

Then I convert it to bytes like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> binary_data;
for (size_t i = 0; i < hex_string.length(); i += 2) {
    std::string byte_string = hex_string.substr(i, 2);
    uint8_t byte_data = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::stoi(byte_string, nullptr, 16));
    binary_data.push_back(byte_data);
}
```

Then I save bytes to file:

```
std::ofstream outfile("output.bin", std::ios::binary);
// Write the binary data to the file
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(binary_data.data()), 
              binary_data.size());
outfile.close();
```

After compile&exec file is not appear in the folder. At the same time std::vector<uint8_t> is not empty, if I add stdout I see all the original bytes there.

I tried to do the same but assign a vector in code and use the same function to save and then it's working:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> binary_data = { 0x5E, 0x3B, 0x64, 0x3B, 0x6A, 0x3B, 0x70, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

What can be a problem here? How can I debug this?

UPDATE:

binary_data before save looks like this:
[binary_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7dNH.png)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253214/discussion-on-question-by-xrails-binary-file-is-not-creating-no-errors-given-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @Aconcagua, i left you a message in the chat. (not sure if you got notified)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I copied the .exe to another pc and it's working fine. Seems it's something with that exact pc where I compiled.

Update:
File was blocked by the av for some reason.

Comment: Maybe your antimalware service doesn't like the payload you're writing. You are writing an executable image after all.

Comment: you're right. upvote.